# How to use a `variables.less` file?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have been using Bootstrap in my website development for some time but I've never had to use a `variables.less` file on a project.

I now have the main `bootstrap.css` and a `variables.less` file that I've customised.

What do I do now, to make the `variables.less` file have effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to compile your less files. Read more on http://lesscss.org/

Comment: I can't just include it or something?

Comment: @user3973427 No, you can't include Less file into CSS file. Note that `bootstrap.css` itself is compiled from Less (or Sass) [sources](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less).

Comment: For development purposes there are server side scripts (or even javascript) that compiles on the fly, but these are not suitable for production use.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to download the bootstrap source (bootstrap less files), add your less file to that source and then compile to get a bootstrap.css that incorporates your changes.

Steps to download bootstrap source and compile it are here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Before compiling, add your custom less file import to bootstrap.less

```
@import "myvariables.less";
```

Make sure to add this import as the last import so that your changes are not overridden.

Compile your bootstrap source to get bootstrap.css that should have your changes.